# How to use matplotlib to add image to the top level of surface of all the existing layers

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a logo to the current plot, which already has existing plot elements. I defined a background in the plot_pic() function. Then plot it, and I want to add a logo to the top surface. I've tried to put the zorder = 10, but it doesn't work. The codes in Jupyter Notebook are:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
from matplotlib.offsetbox import  OffsetImage
%matplotlib inline

from matplotlib.patches import Circle, Rectangle, Arc, Ellipse


def plot_pic(ax=None, color='black', lw=2, scale = 15):
    # get the current ax if ax is None
    if ax is None:
        ax = plt.gca()


    big_box =  Rectangle((-34 * scale, 0), width = 68 * scale, height = 105 / 2 * scale, linewidth=lw, color=color, fill=False)

    middle_box =  Rectangle((-(7.32 * scale / 2+ 5.5 * scale +11 * scale),0), width = (5.5 * scale * 2 + 11 * scale * 2 + 7.32 * scale), height = 16.5 * scale, linewidth = lw, color = color, fc = "white")

    small_box = Rectangle((-(7.32 * scale/ 2 + 5.5 * scale), 0), width = 7.32 * scale + 5.5 * scale * 2, height = 5.5 * scale, linewidth = lw, color = color, fill = False)

    arc = Circle((0, 11 * scale), radius = 9.15 * scale, color = color, lw = lw, fill = False, zorder = 0)

    # List of elements to be plotted
    pic_elements = [big_box, middle_box, small_box, arc]


    # Add the elements onto the axes
    for element in pic_elements:
        ax.add_patch(element)

    return ax

fig = plt.figure()
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
ax = plt.subplot()
logo=mpimg.imread('rbl_logo.png')
# You have to add your own logo, this is in my own folder
addLogo = OffsetImage(logo, zoom=0.6, zorder = 10)
addLogo.set_offset((200,-10)) # pass the position in a tuple
ax.add_artist(addLogo)
plt.xlim(-600,600)
plt.ylim(-100,1000)
plot_pic()
```

The result is that, the plot_pic() layer covers part of the logo that I wanted to show, and I just want to place the logo on the very top surface that covers all the elements below.

[image]

Is there anyway to do so? Thank you very much.

Comment: You are plotting the logo first and then calling the function `plot_pic` which makes the plots in the `plot_pic` overlap the logo. Try the other way round.

Comment: I'll try this solution as well, though ImportanceOfBeingErnest's answer actually solved the issue perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: Just try putting the last line `plot_pic()` before `logo=mpimg.imread('rbl_logo.png')`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that setting the zorder with the keyword arguments sets the zorder of the image inside the OffsetBox, which will have no effect. In order to set the zorder of the box itself, you need to set this externally:

```
addLogo = OffsetImage(logo, zoom=0.6)
addLogo.set_zorder(10)
```