# How to add logo to below of the x axis in the matplotlib charts

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to add logo to the bottom right of the chart using matplotlib.

My logo is not fitting in the proper position.

my logo source="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cldougl/plot_images/add_r_img/vox.png"

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt#
from matplotlib.offsetbox import  OffsetImage
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
logo=image.imread("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cldougl/plot_images/add_r_img/vox.png")
# You have to add your own logo, this is in my own folder
addLogo = OffsetImage(logo, zoom=0.4)
#addLogo.set_zorder(100)
addLogo.set_offset((250,-25)) # pass the position in a tuple
ax.add_artist(addLogo)
height = [6, 10, 5, 18, 45]
bars = ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')
y = np.arange(len(bars))
plt.bar(y, height, color=(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6))
```

[image]

In jupyter notebook logo is like mirror.
[image]

Comment: @importanceofbeingernest I want to add logo below x axis, not in the plot area. All available answers are showing logo in the inside plot.

Comment: There isn't really that much of a difference if the image is in- or outside the axes. Also consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628902/how-to-use-matplotlib-to-add-image-to-the-top-level-of-surface-of-all-the-existi). If those do not help, please ask a question where you show what you have tried and in how far it failed.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I have added my output. My logo is not showing properly. Can you tell me how can i fix the same. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The logo is positionned outside the figure. Use `0` or higher instead of `-25` in the position. If you then need more room for the logo, adjust the subplot position, e.g. `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.3)`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest how can I change logo size and position.?

Comment: `.set_offset((x,y))` with `x` and `y` being the coordinates in pixels.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest and for logo size?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest In jupyter notebook logo is showing reversed image.I have updated in the code.

Comment: I reopened the question,because it has now evolved away from the initial problem. I cannot reproduce the inversion of the image. So I fear I cannot help more.